# Extending an Ant path?

Tags: ant

What does it mean to extend a path with another path in ANT?

if I have the folloing:

```
<path>
  <pathelement path="build/classes;lib/junit.jar" />
</path>
```

Does it mean that  Ant breaks `build/classes;lib/junit.jar` into `build/classes` and `lib/junit.jar`

in other words, does ant think that we are defining two path elements?

Thank you so much in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your example got lost, probably because you didn't select it and click the code button (the "101010" icon on the post toolbar)

Answer (score 3):

Your example:

```
<path>
  <pathelement path="build/classes;lib/junit.jar" />
</path>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<path>
  <pathelement path="build/classes" />
  <pathelement path="lib/junit.jar" />
</path>
```

in both cases the path that created includes the contents of the `build/classes` directory plus the contents of the jarfile `lib/junit.jar`.

This mechanism allows you to dynamically create the required paths within your build file, rather than having to construct the combined string `build/classes;lib/junit.jar`.

For example, if you had the classes directory and the path to the junit jar specified in properties, you could than combine them into a single path:

```
<property name="classes.dir" location="build/classes" />
<property name="junit.jar" location="lib/junit.jar" />

...

<path>
  <pathelement path="${classes.dir}" />
  <pathelement path="${junit.jar}" />
</path>
```

This path would be the same as the examples above.

You could also refer to each of these items individually in other parts of your build file, and would only have to make changes in one place if either value needed to be changed.

Comment: Agreed this is a better answer than mine and deserves to be accepted

Answer (score 0):

The operation of the **pathelement** tag is documented [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)

> You can specify PATH- and
>   CLASSPATH-type references using both
>   ":" and ";" as separator characters.
>   Ant will convert the separator to the
>   correct character of the current
>   operating system.

Comment: does that mean that build/classes;lib/junit.jar will become one path, as in build/classes/lib/junit.jar depending on the system?

Comment: Assuming that you are on windows, the two jars will appear on the path you're creating. Add a **id** attribute to the path and you can reference it from commands like javac, taskdef, etc.